# I am coding a game where i have a list of list of buttons and i wish to pass a on click command based on there coordinate in the grid

Tags: python, loops, configuration, tkinter

I am coding a game where i have a list of list of buttons and i wish to pass a on click command based on there coordinate in the grid. When i run the program the event only effects the last button of the list and i dont understand why. It is like if all the buttons took the same coordinates.

```
from random import randint
from Tkinter import *



###functions
def mine(x,y):#permet de savoir si ya une mine ou combien ya de mine autour


     quantite=0

     if bombe[(x+1)][y]==99:
         quantite=quantite+1
     if bombe[x-1][y]==99:
         quantite=quantite+1
     if bombe[x][y+1]==99:
         quantite=quantite+1
     if bombe[x][y-1]==99:
        quantite=quantite+1
     if bombe[x-1][y-1]==99:
        quantite=quantite+1
     if bombe[x+1][y+1]==99:
        quantite=quantite+1
     if bombe[x+1][y-1]==99:
            quantite=quantite+1
     if bombe[x-1][y+1]==99:
            quantite=quantite+1
     if bombe[x][y]==99:
            quantite=99   

     demineur[(x)][(y)].configure(text=str(quantite), state='disabled')

    ####


 ###creer le tableau et placer les mine aléatoirement tableau de 10x10
bombe = [[0 for a in range(10)] for b in range(10) ] #creer mon tableau demineur "a=axe x" "b=axe y"


i=0
while i<20:#placer des bombes aléatoirement dans le jeux qui est 10 par 10
        x = (randint(0,9))
        y = (randint(0,9))
        if bombe[x][y]==0:
           bombe[x][y]=99

           i=i+1


root = Tk()

root.title("Demineur")#title de la window
root.geometry("450x550")#size de la widow
app = Frame(root)
app.grid()


demineur = [[ Button(app, text = str((j)*10+(i+1)), height = 2, width = 4) for i in range (10)] for j in range (10)] #creer les button de mon interface 10 par 10


x=1
for i in range(0,9):
     y=1
     for j in range (0,9):
          demineur[x][y].configure(command= lambda: mine(x, y))
          y=y+1
     x=x+1

ranger=1
colonne=1
for i in demineur:
    colonne=1
    for j in i:
        j.grid(row=ranger, column=colonne)
        colonne=colonne+1
    ranger=ranger+1



root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What problem do you have?  You have only posted some code.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a go-to for having your homework done for you. Show us instead what you have tried, and what the problem seems to be.

Comment: this is what i have tried i know for a fact that if i assign one by one the command to each button that my program runs but when i try to mae a mor efficient code by using a for loop to assign my commands to the buttons, the event will happen only on the last button of the list as if all the buttons had the same coordinate... i dont know if its a little bit clearer?? Also this is not a homework this is for fun i am trying to learn python on my own since i already know BASIC.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked multiple times in various ways, but I did not find a single answer I like.  The key idea is that you must capture the *value* of the arguments, in this case, the value of x and y, *when you assign the command*. One way is using default args with a lambda expression.

```
      demineur[x][y].configure(command= lambda x=x, y=y: mine(x, y))
```

This may be clearer if the captured values are given different names.

```
      demineur[x][y].configure(command= lambda xn=x, yn=y: mine(xn, yn))
```

Or define a wrap function.

```
def wrap(x, y): return mine(x, y)
....
      demineur[x][y].configure(command=wrap(x, y))
```

Or use partial from the functools module.

```
from functools import partial
...
      demineur[x][y].configure(command=partial(mine, x, y)
```

PS

```
x=1
for i in range(0,9):
     y=1
     for j in range (0,9):
          demineur[x][y].configure(command= lambda: mine(x, y))
          y=y+1
     x=x+1
```

is much easier to read and understand rewritten as

```
for x in range(1, 10):
     for y in range (1, 10):
          demineur[x][y].configure(command= lambda: mine(x, y))
```

Ditto for the next nested loop.